# Excel Pivot Table Date Grouping Issue

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have used the group option in excel to group the date as per weeks.

I copied the same pivot table in another sheet. In the new sheet, I, want the dates to be grouped as per months. When I change the group option from week to month the format is also changing in the previos pivot table which is as per week.

I want the same information grouped as per weeks and months in different or same sheet.

Regards
Heera Chavan

Comment: Rather than copy the pivot, can you just create a new pivot and adjust as necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping a pivot table affects the pivot cache and all pivot tables built off the same pivot cache will adopt the same grouping.

In order for pivot tables to have different groupings, you need to create a pivot table with a new pivot cache. There are two ways to do that.

1. Start with an existing pivot table, then change the pivot data source to a different range. Refresh. That may create some nonsense, but stay with me. Next, change the pivot data source again and select the original source. This will create a new pivot cache. Refresh.
2. use the legacy pivot table wizard, which you can invoke with Alt-D-P and follow the prompts.